# Crashkernel is still being added by update-grub after removing linux-crashdump

Tags: grub2, kernel, configuration

Once I installed `linux-crashdump` by following [this tutorial](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Kernel/CrashdumpRecipe).

But I don't need it any more, so I removed the `linux-crashdump`, `crash` and `kdump-tools` packages.

Regardless, the `crashkernel` kernel parameter is still being added to my `grub.cfg` by the `update-grub` script, so 128M of my memory is still being reserved for nothing. I don't understand why. I don't have this argument in `/etc/default/grub`, and I also looked through `/etc/grub.d/10_linux`, but I couldn't find where the "crashkernel" argument comes from.

I still have the `kexec-tools` package installed, because meanwhile I found it nifty, as it provides much quicker reboots. But I don't think that causes the crashkernel argument to be added.

Comment: Try to `grep -Ri crashkernel /etc/*`...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found the culprit:

```
root@vmhost:~# grep -Ri crashkernel /etc/*
/etc/default/grub.d/kexec-tools.cfg:GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="$GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT crashkernel=384M-:128M"
```

Thanks to @Jan!

I didn't know that GRUB has additional config in `/etc/default/grub.d`. After removing this file, `crashkernel` is not being added anymore. Seems it belongs to `kexec-tools`, after all. Hope it won't come back with a future kexec-tools update.

Comment: Indeed. See [#1318111](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/kexec-tools/+bug/1318111).